# Regex replace string in the format @...@....@

Tags: c#, regex

How can I replace the following string from this:

```
"Hello @app@username@, my name is @app@name@."
```

To

```
"Hello <span>@app@username@</span>, my name is <span>@app@name@</span>."
```

There are a large number of application variable `@app@variable@`.

Comment: What did you try? You should try yourself first and show the code where you got stuck on. **You should not use regex for this**, use `String.Replace`. Regex will make it very complicated to debug. Regex is the last option in the list of 1000

Comment: Please show us your code. We'll check your regex and help to fix it or provide alternative solution

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Ok how would you use String.Replace, There are move application variable i should add to the question. I don't know all the application variables

Comment: How do you expect to replace everything if you don't know every variable?

Comment: @Valter something like: `var newString = "Hello @app@username@, my name is @app@name@.".Replace("@app@username@", "<span>@app@username@</span>").Replace("@app@name@", "<span>@app@name@</span>");`

Comment: Well either you can use your custom logic using for loop to replace your app variables one by one. OR you can use any existing tmeplate engine which can do this job for you. OR you can use regex with Groups and callback for replacing string which can do your job. Let me know what you prefer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the pattern:

```
@[A-Za-z]+@[A-Za-z]+@
```

And replace it like:

```
string input = "Hello @app@username@, my name is @app@name@.";

string result = Regex.Replace(input, "@[A-Za-z]+@[A-Za-z]+@", match => "<span>" + match.Value + "</span>");
```

Note that if the matches are always in the form: `@app@someotherword@` you can use the regex:

```
@app@[A-Za-z]+@
```

As @WiktorStribiżew comments you can also use the `$&` backreference to perform the replace:

```
Regex.Replace(input, "@[A-Za-z]+@[A-Za-z]+@", "<span>$&</span>");
```

Comment: this differs from my answer how? you even copied the variable names...

Comment: @fubo input and result are common names for something like this. Mine allows for a common format I,e, `@...@...@` whereas yours allows for multiple `@`s i.e. `@..@...@...@` and I have also provided an alternative solution for the specific format i.e. `@app@something@`

Comment: @fubo Oh and mine allows for uppercase characters whereas yours appears to be lower case only. If you have a problem with people writing up _similar_ answers take it to meta.

Comment: Why use a match evaluator? There is `$&` backreference. `Regex.Replace(input, "@[A-Za-z]+@[A-Za-z]+@", "<span>$&</span>");`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Mainly because I thought it was `$1` and couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 6):

This code puts `<span></span>` tags around every variable.

```
string input = "Hello @app@username@, my name is @app@name@.";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, "[@][a-z@]+[@]", s => "<span>" + s.Value + "</span>");
```

**UPDATE:**

as Wiktor Stribiżew mentioned there is even a shorter way to write it:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, "[@][a-z@]+[@]", "<span>$&</span>");
```

Comment: I think in OP's case, `@app@\w+@` or `@app@[a-zA-Z]+@` should work too, depending what he's trying to do.

Comment: Why use a match evaluator? There is `$&` backreference. `Regex.Replace(input, "[@][a-z@]+[@]", "<span>$&</span>");`